# Aluminium foil for cooking

Tags: acid-base

I have heard so many times that aluminium pots should not be used to cook sour (acid) foods and I would like to know **the chemical  reason** for that claim.

I also would like to know if the aluminium foils are not suitable only for cooking sour foods, or if this extends to **storing** sour (acid) food such as lemon juice?

Comment: The reason is that Al will react with acids. This applies to packaging as well as cooking.

Comment: Why [not Al?](http://theconversation.com/why-you-shouldnt-wrap-your-food-in-aluminium-foil-before-cooking-it-57220)

Comment: Frankly, Al oxidised in thin air jus like that...[think how badly it would react with acidic food.](http://www.thekitchn.com/food-science-explaining-reacti-73723)

Comment: [This](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5798) and cooking.stackexchange have had few more curious question like yours.

Comment: While acidic foods do react with aluminium slightly, the main reason not to use aluminium utensils for those foods isn't the danger from dissolved aluminium salts (which is very low) but the damage done to the aluminium utensils (anodised aluminium surfaces are worn away, though they can be regenerated by using other foods).

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80941/would-swallowing-aluminum-foil-be-considered-dangerous

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/165315-overview) that explains the toxicity of Aluminum ions.

Comment: Aluminum is also a poor choice for salt containing foods ( if wet).